# Model identifiability when manually creating variables

Tags: regression, categorical-data

I'd like to know if my intuition is correct. We have data where each patient can essentially have one of three categories of treatment over a period of time:

1. untreated
2. class 1 treatment
3. class 2 treatment

It might not be ideal but we want to code treatment as 3 'proportion of time on treatment' variables. So, for example, if a patient for the duration of their observation is untreated they will get a 1 in the untreated column and a 0 in the other two columns. Otherwise the proportion of time on each treatment will be recorded.

Because the total proportion of time treated for each patient should sum to 1, I should exclude one of the variables right? (in a similar way to creating k - 1 dummies from a categorical variable).

Comment: The title seems to be about identifiability, but the body seems to allude to multicollinearity. These are similar in a way, but they're not really the same. Can you clarify what your question is about?

Comment: I thought I understood collinearity but maybe I have the concepts of model identifiability and multicollinearity mixed up - happy to have this explained. I really just want to know if in a regression model it is ok to include all 3 proportion of time variables (even though any one is a linear combination of the other two). I would have thought not.

Comment: Multicollinearity can result in inflated standard errors, which may or may not be a problem depending on what exactly you are trying to do. If you are looking to compute statistical significance using something like a Wald's test then I suspect you should drop one of the variables. If you only care about statistical prediction, then don't worry about including both provided the estimation (e.g. condition number) is numerically stable.

Comment: For causal inference it is impossible for me to determine with the info provided whether either choice is appropriate b/c you would need a causal model to ID the valid adjustment set for the estimand.